# Can I reference/load a <datalist> from a separate file?

Tags: javascript, html, html-datalist

I am creating a Google Chrome extension that is basically just a dropdown menu and an input box with datalists. Changing the selection in the dropdown menu changes which datalist the input box uses. I have about a hundred datalists and some of them have thousands of options. I'm looking for a way to reduce the load time of the html file (currently about 930 kb) and I want to keep the datalists in a separate html file and only reference them when I change the dropdown selection.

Example html file

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
Select Food group
<select id="foodgroup">
    <option>Select One</option>
    <option>Vegetable</option>
    <option>Fruit</option>
</select>
<br /><br />
Enter name of food
<br /><br />
<input id="entry"></input>
<datalist id="Vegetable">
    <option>Pumpkin</option>
    <option>Squash</option>
    <option>Carrot</option>
    <option>Lettuce</option>
    <option>Bell Pepper</option>
</datalist>
<datalist id="Fruit">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Pineapple</option>
    <option>Strawberry</option>
</datalist>
```

Example js file

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var box = document.getElementById('entry');
    var fg = document.getElementById('foodgroup');
    function swapList(){
        box.value="";
        var list = fg.value;
        box.setAttribute('list', list);
    }
    document.getElementById("foodgroup").onchange = swapList;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create arrays in JavaScript containing your various datalists. These can be housed in a separate file if needed and be linked to with a script tag. The snippet below shows the arrays defined locally since the external file does not exist for this snippet.
On selection of the food type, the appropriate array can be used to create a new DOM elements for the datalists:

```js
var foodgroup = document.getElementById("foodgroup");
var datalistCont = document.getElementById("datalistCont");
//
function start() {
  foodgroup.addEventListener("change", loadDatalist);
}
//
function loadDatalist() {
  datalistCont.innerHTML = "";
  var food = foodgroup.options[foodgroup.selectedIndex].value;
  //
  if (food == "fruit" || food == "veg") {
    var inp = document.createElement("INPUT");
    datalistCont.appendChild(inp);
    inp.setAttribute('list', food);
    //
    var dl = document.createElement("DATALIST");
    dl.id = food;
    datalistCont.appendChild(dl);
    //
    newDatalist = document.getElementById(food);
    //
    var selectedArray = window[food];
    for (var x = 0; x < selectedArray.length; x++) {
      var opt = document.createElement("OPTION");
      opt.value = selectedArray[x];
      newDatalist.appendChild(opt);
    }
  }
}
//
veg = ["Pumpkin", "Squash", "Carrot", "Lettuce", "Bell Pepper"];
fruit = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Pineapple", "Strawberry"];
//
window.load = start();
```

```html
Select Food group
<select id="foodgroup">
  <option value="none">Select One</option>
  <option value="veg">Vegetable</option>
  <option value="fruit">Fruit</option>
</select>
<br />
<div id="datalistCont"></div>
```